# Is there a way to create a Box from a Vec<u8> that implements the Read trait?

Tags: rust, ownership

I'm writing a piece of code that using the lopdf crate writes a PDF on a Vec. Then I want to print the PDF via the IPP crate but it requires a Box that I'm not able to create

I've tried many things, but I'm always stuck with ownerships problems.
Another thing I tried was creating the Box from a raw pointer but it did crash the program.

```rust
let mut doc = Document::load("file.pdf").unwrap();
let mut doc_bytes = Vec::new();
//redacted
doc.save_to(&mut doc_bytes);
let doc_slice = doc_bytes.as_slice();
let buffer = std::io::BufReader::new(doc_slice.to_vec().as_slice());
let doc_box = Box::from(buffer);
let client = ipp::IppClient::new("printer URL");
let print_job = ipp::operation::PrintJob::new(doc_box, &"username", None)
client.send(print_job).unwrap();
```

It should print the file on the printer. It won't compile saying that

```
temporary value dropped while borrowed

creates a temporary which is freed while still in use rustc(E0716)
main.rs(6, 70): creates a temporary which is freed while still in use
main.rs(6, 100): temporary value is freed at the end of this statement
main.rs(9, 79): cast requires that borrow lasts for `'static`
```

on `doc_slice.to_vec()`.

Essentially, I'm trying to do something like this (https://github.com/dremon/ipp.rs/blob/master/ipp-client/examples/print-job.rs), but without reading from a file.

### Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

`Cargo.toml`

```
[package]
name = "example"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["you <you@example.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
ipp = "0.2.1"
```

`main.rs`

```rust
fn main(){
  let mut doc_bytes = Vec::<u8>::new();
  doc_bytes.set_len(720000);
  let client = ipp::IppClient::new("http://printer_url");
  let print_job = ipp::operation::PrintJob::new(doc_bytes.into_boxed_slice(), &"user", None);
  client.send(print_job).unwrap();
}
```

With this code I get two errors:

```
   Compiling example v0.1.0 (/path)
error[E0277]: the trait bound `[u8]: std::io::Read` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:5:49
  |
5 |   let print_job = ipp::operation::PrintJob::new(doc_bytes.into_boxed_slice(), &"username", None);
  |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::io::Read` is not implemented for `[u8]`
  |
  = help: the following implementations were found:
            <&'a [u8] as std::io::Read>
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::io::Read`

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `[u8]` cannot be known at compilation time
 --> src/main.rs:5:49
  |
5 |   let print_job = ipp::operation::PrintJob::new(doc_bytes.into_boxed_slice(), &"username", None);
  |                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
  |
  = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `[u8]`
  = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
  = note: required for the cast to the object type `dyn std::io::Read`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
error: Could not compile `pettorine`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

I've noticed that I get a new error!

Thanks in advance for all your support

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.into_boxed_slice

Comment: and Read is already implemented `Impl<'_> Read for &'_ [u8]`

Comment: @turbulencetoo the compiler says that `the trait bound \`[u8]: std::io::Read\` is not satisfied. the trait \`std::io::Read\` is not implemented for \`[u8]\``

Comment: But it is implemented for &[u8], and A Box<[u8]> should deref to a &[u8]

Comment: actually looking at it on the playground I had to so something like `(&my_box_u8 as &[u8]).read(buffer_to_read_into);` which is weird and I'm sure someone else has a more elegant way of getting a `&[u8]` out of a `Box<[u8]>`

Comment: @turbulencetoo thanks for your support. First of all, I'm a novice in Rust, so pardon my ignorance. Then, why are you trying to get a `&[u8]` out of a `Box<[u8]>`? I just need a  `Box<>` that implements the `Read` trait, which I'm not able to get.

Comment: Well that first link I shared is the way to go from` Vec<u8>` to `Box<[u8]>`... but I am similarly having trouble with the fact that `Box<[u8]>` doesn't implement `Read`. I am a Rust novice too

Comment: Also It looks like doing `(&*my_box_u8)` is a better way to get something Read-able than my previous suggestion of`(&my_box_u8 as &[u8])`

Comment: Could you provide a [MCVE] with the corresponding error message? The [Rust tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) contains tips on how to create this. I guess your question is not related to the actual problem you want to solve.

Comment: @TimDiekmann I've posted the code you requested. I see there's the unknown size at compile time thing that could mess up the code but I don't know how could I fix it because the vec contains a file, which has variable size

Comment: I think your example may be a little too minimal. It looks like the compiler can't infer the type of data that is stored into your `Vec`. Can you try to create is with: `let mut doc_bytes = Vec::<u8>::new();`?

Comment: @Jmb I've made some edits and I've specified the maximum size of the Vec

Comment: `Vec<u8>` dereferences to `&[u8]`, so you shouldn't need to call `into_boxed_slice`. Instead `&(&doc_bytes as &[u8]) as &Read` gives you a reference to a `Read`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found the answer (https://github.com/dremon/ipp.rs/issues/6)

```
let mut doc = Document::load("pettorina.pdf").unwrap();
let mut doc_bytes = Vec::new();
let mut num = " ".repeat(((4.0 -(pettorina.numero as f32).log10().floor())/2.0) as usize);
num.push_str(&pettorina.numero.to_string());
doc.version = "1.4".to_string();
doc.replace_text(1, "num", &num);
doc.replace_text(1, "NOME", &pettorina.nome.to_ascii_uppercase());
doc.save_to(&mut doc_bytes);
let client = ipp::IppClient::new("printer_url");
let print_job = ipp::operation::PrintJob::new(Box::new(std::io::Cursor::new(doc_bytes)), &"pettorine", None);
client.send(print_job).unwrap();
```